# what is the maximum sound recording capacity of mobile hardware?

Tags: android, audio, mobile, audio-recording

I am developing an android app for recording the sound. In my app i will display the SPL (Sound Pressure Level) in dB. As part of my search, i come across, mobile hardware can only record sounds up to <= 110 dB. The reason is, mobiles are designed for human voice recording and that falls under the range of 60 dB. So if i need to record the sounds which is more than 110 dB how the mobile hardware will respond to that? Do i need to depend upon external devices and not the mobiles? Please provide your comments.

Thanks & regards,
Siva.

Comment: i think it is depends upon how much free size of memory is available on device

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme - the questions is about sound level, not the recording length.

Comment: ohh sorry as per my knowldge when i tried to record the voice through programatically its maximum frequency was 44100hz so as per this value level will be consider

Comment: Yes, Its about the sound level. My concern is, does the mobile hardware - audio recording circuit, uses some filters that keeps the db level around 100 dB. Or can we do some thing to extract real dB levels using Android API.

Comment: [This page describes](http://www.rodemic.com/faq/what-is-meant-by-the-term-maximum-spl) the maximum SPL threshold for Rode mics. I would suspect the mobile phone would have much worse characteristics in that regard. Anyway, [apparently to loud sound could even break the microphone](http://www.dvinfo.net/forum/all-things-audio/9896-loud-noise-damage-microphone.html), so be careful.

Comment: @Androidiseverythingforme - Thanks for your post. Frequency is probably a different element of sound recording which calculates per second. i would like to know the dB value which is the magnitude of the sound.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is in fact about the *dynamic range* of the audio input of a mobile phone - any value you record must be capable of being represented in the scale used to measure it.

There is an associated question of what the largest sound pressure level that a particular phone can record, but this is ultimately limited by the dynamic range and the design of transducer used.  Any absolutely measure is relative a calibration point - which in digital audio systems is dB FSD (e.g. ratio sample to maximum), yielding negative values.

The dynamic range in dB of a ideal PCM system is limited by quantisation noise and is related directly to bit-depth (Q) of the sample:

```
SQNR = 20*log10(2 ^ Q) =~ 6.02Q
```

State-of-the-art ADCs used in pro-audio equipment typically have 24-bit sample depth giving a SQNR of 144dB.  It's worth noting, that in silicon ADCs and DACs, the thermal noise floor of the analogue section of the converter is smaller than this, and the LSB might as well be random.

AFAIK, Android is using 16-bit PCM, which has a SQNR of 96dB.  This is the same performance as the CD Audio standard.  A SNR of 110dB wouldn't be bad for pro-audio equipment.

In practice, audio quality is rarely a headline feature of phones and most get nowhere near this. Most users use crappy headphones or the on-board speaker of their phone for voice calls and won't notice the difference.   It's an obvious corner to cut from both a cost and power budget point of view for a phone manufacturer.

Additionally, good digital audio design is a black-art. Factors such as decoupling of digital signals from ground and physical proximity of analogue components come into play.  You find that in tear-downs of Apple kit, they often place the codec right next to the headphone jack, and away from the main board of the system. Again, other cost-conscious manufactures don't do this, and it'll degrade the dynamic range of the system.

In order to get meaningful measurements from the audio input you will need to disable both automatic gain control (AGC) and probably the HFP (used to remove DC bias, and often set with Fc > 100Hz for voice calls).

If your intention is to record absolute SPL, you will need to calibrate the audio system of the device to a set-point.  There is no standardisation of this between manufacturers (or even devices from any given manufacturer).  Unless you fancy doing this for the devices on the market (of which there are a lot), you'll never provide universally accurate measurements.

Comment: Thanks marko for your detailed explanation. it helps me understanding what i am actually looking for.